# is bower install html5boilerplate is a good thing ?

Tags: html, npm, bower, html5boilerplate

My question is it good to install html5boilerplate with bower?
How can one proceed after that as it have its own directory for css and javascript and everything will come under bower_component/html5boilerplate

Answer (score 21):

No, use Yeoman http://yeoman.io/ is even better than download the .zip

note: you need nodejs installed to install Yeoman

Install: `npm install -g yo`

https://github.com/h5bp/generator-h5bp

Install: `npm install -g generator-h5bp`

Run it with yo: `yo h5bp`

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not.

- **HTML5 Boilerplate** is meant to be used as a base for starting a new project.
- **Bower** is a great way to manage libraries that are going to be used in a project, like jQuery or AngularJS.

The better thing for you to do is to download the HTML5 Boilerplate zip and extract its files into your project root folder.

Comment: avoiding manual downloading, extracting, copy, pasting is exactly is exactly why to use a task manager.

Comment: Yes, an automation tool such as Yeoman is the ideal solution here, I do agree that the above answer is better. I just wanted to stay very basic at at pointing out that HTML5 Boilerplate is not a Front-end dependency and as such should not be installed with Bower.